# HTML div cuts other div off

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a little web page and my problem is that 1 `div` cuts out a part of my second `div`:

[image]

As you can see the 3 gets cut I think its a `CSS` Problem but I don't know where...

HTML(just the part with the 2 divs):

```css
* {
  cursor: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.number {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 500pt;
  margin: 0;
padding:0  background-color: transparent;
}
p {
  font-size: 70pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.names {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  width: 400px;
  height: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.lauftext {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 70pt;
}
@keyframes marquee {
0% {
text-indent: 100%
}
100% {
text-indent: -100%
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
0% {
text-indent: 100%
}
100% {
text-indent: -100%
}
}
.lauftextdiv {
  height: 100%;
}
.lauftext {
  height: 200pt;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 200pt;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
  webkit-animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
from {
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
to {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
}
@-o-keyframes rotate {
from {
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
to {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
from {
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
to {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
from {
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
to {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
}
.number_full {
  text-align: center;
  animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
}
.number_full h1 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 100px #777;
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 600pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width" , inital-scale=1.0>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../layouts/style.css">
  <script src="../reload.js"></script>
  <title>3</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="number">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="names"> Marc
    ... 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your full code or working example? Currently what is causing the issue cannot be figured out.

Comment: I don't see any part cutting in this example.

Comment: Not in the snippet... Ill change it w8

Comment: @Bhansa now we cant even see the number... How can i make it the name transparent

Comment: <h1> tag element is not visible in your demo.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq You can see a very small part and thats my Problem xD

Comment: I don't think other div is cutting your content. You have `overflow:hidden` on all of your elements. For this element you also have fixed height and huge font size. Working with fixed values and hidden overflow will cause this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should add a `position` property to the `.number` too. And try to remove the `height` property, or set it to `100%`.

```
.number {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;

  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.number {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 300pt;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
  background-color: transparent;
}

p {
  font-size: 70pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.names {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  width: 400px;
  height: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lauftext {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 70pt;
}

@keyframes marquee {
 0% { text-indent: 100% }
 100% { text-indent: -100% }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% { text-indent: 100% }
  100% { text-indent: -100% }
}

.lauftextdiv {
 height: 100%;
}

.lauftext {
 height: 200pt;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 200pt;
 top: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
    animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
    webkit-animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}

.number_full {
 text-align: center;
 animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
}

.number_full h1 {
 text-shadow: 0 0 100px #777;
 transform: rotateX(20deg);
 padding: 100px;
 font-size: 600pt;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width" , inital-scale=1.0>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../layouts/style.css">
 <script src="../reload.js"></script>
    <title>3</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="number">
 <h1>3</h1>
</div>
<div class="names">
Marc
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing the `height` property from the `.number`. Or make it 100% if needed.

Comment: Ty height made it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a closing tag on your h1, it should be.

```
<div class="number">
    <h1>3</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is not cut off by the other div, it is cut off by:

```
.number {height: 60%;}
```

Change this to:

```
.number {height: 100%;}
```

This will fix it. If you need to have the height at 60%, you have to make the overflow visible with:

```
.number {height: 60%; overflow:visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the CSS

overflow: visible;

```
* {
    cursor: none !important;
    overflow: visible;
}
```